# What is the proper way to execute a batchfile with multiple params?

Tags: delphi, batch-file

I have a batchfile which I use for managing the translation of various programs.
Now I want a delphi application to call this batchfile and pass on the parameter it needs for further processing. Unfortunately the parameters contain spaces which leads to a splitup. Is there a way to keep all parameters tied up as intended?
this is how my batchfile looks:

```
ECHO Scan for new ressources
%MLDIR%\Ml7Build.exe s %1%

ECHO Import glossary for new translation
%MLDIR%\MlBuild.exe i %2%

ECHO Create translated application
%MLDIR%\Ml7Build.exe b %3%
```

I tried to use the ShellExecute-Command from ShellApi because I found several similar questions on SO, but none of them could help me in solving my problem. My delphi code looks like this:

```
 param1 := ExtractFileName(hMLProj);
 param2 := '-f: '+MLWorkDir+'Prev_'+ExtractFileName(hMLProj)+' -settings:Auftrag_Test.importsettings-method:2 -overwri:3 -error:2 '+ExtractFileName(hMLProj)+' ';
 param3 := ExtractFileName(hMLProj);
 ShellExecute(0,'open',PCHAR(MLWorkDir+'__AutomatedTranslationFUBAR.bat'),PChar(param1 +param2 +param3),nil,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: Use `"` to group text into single arguments. For instance `"foo bar"` is a single argument. I'd personally use `CreateProcess` here rather than `ShellExecute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ECHO Scan for new resources
%MLDIR%\Ml7Build.exe s %~1

ECHO Import glossary for new translation
%MLDIR%\MlBuild.exe i %~2
REM is 7 ^ omitted here?

ECHO Create translated application
%MLDIR%\Ml7Build.exe b %~3
```

Note that `%n` **not** `%n%` (n=1..9) refers to the parameter `n` supplied to the batch. The tilde removes "any enclosing quotes."

Parameters require to be "enclosed in quotes" (and they must be double-quotes) if they contain separators such as spaces.